# How do i delete Multiple Row of Record in this code

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

```
private void btnDel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to Delete this Record?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Stop) == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        using (SFCDataContext SFC = new SFCDataContext())
        {
            var countRec = SFC.Systems_MonitoringMeasurementHeaders.Where(t => t.DocNO == DocNum.Text && t.DetailsDocNum == clsVariable.GetDocNumRecord).Count();
            if (countRec > 0)
            {
                Systems_MonitoringMeasurementHeader Table = SFC.Systems_MonitoringMeasurementHeaders.FirstOrDefault(r => r.DocNO == DocNum.Text && r.DetailsDocNum == clsVariable.GetDocNumRecord);
                SFC.Systems_MonitoringMeasurementHeaders.DeleteOnSubmit(Table);
            }

            var countRecDetails = SFC.Systems_MonitoringMeasurementDetails.Where(y => y.DocNO == DocNum.Text && y.DetailsDocNum == clsVariable.GetDocNumRecord).Count(); <-- Starts here..
            if (countRecDetails > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < countRecDetails; i++)
                {
                    Systems_MonitoringMeasurementDetail TableDetails = SFC.Systems_MonitoringMeasurementDetails.FirstOrDefault(w => w.DocNO == DocNum.Text && w.DetailsDocNum == clsVariable.GetDocNumRecord);
                    SFC.Systems_MonitoringMeasurementDetails.DeleteOnSubmit(TableDetails);
                }
            } <-- Til here

            SFC.SubmitChanges();
            SFC.Connection.Close();
            gfunc.setMessageBox("Delete Successful!", 2);
            ClearFields(2);
            btnSetLock(true, false, true, false, false, false, false, true);
            DocNum.Enabled = true;
            DocNum.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

the problem is while deleting the details record it does perform a delete but its only deleting one row. instead of 5 or more.. and it only takes the 1st entry. i made a for loop statement by count of the record found by the referrence in the debug it shows the exact count of record ex. 5 so it loops on deleting record 5 times but then only delete the 1st entry the rest none. why is it? please help.

-- UPDATE --

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure to Delete this Record?", "Delete", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Stop) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                using (SFCDataContext SFC = new SFCDataContext())
                {
                    var countRec = SFC.Systems_MonitoringMeasurementHeaders.Where(t => t.DocNO == DocNum.Text && t.DetailsDocNum == clsVariable.GetDocNumRecord);
                    if (countRec.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        SFC.Systems_MonitoringMeasurementHeaders.DeleteAllOnSubmit(countRec.ToList());
                    }

                    var countRecDetails = SFC.Systems_MonitoringMeasurementDetails.Where(y => y.DocNO == DocNum.Text && y.DetailsDocNum == clsVariable.GetDocNumRecord);
                    if (countRecDetails.Count() > 0)
                    {
                        SFC.Systems_MonitoringMeasurementDetails.DeleteAllOnSubmit(countRecDetails.ToList());                        
                    }

                    SFC.SubmitChanges();
                    SFC.Connection.Close(); 
                }
                gfunc.setMessageBox("Delete Successful!", 2);
                ClearFields(2);
                btnSetLock(true, false, true, false, false, false, false, true);
                DocNum.Enabled = true;
                DocNum.Focus();
            }
```

It works but i don't know if it's ok or not.

Comment: did you try this by SFC.SubmitChanges() in for loop?

Comment: @masoumehkarvar making even more queries than he already have?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your solution is not working, because you are querying for entity to delete in a loop, but you do not submit changes on each step. Thus you are getting exactly same first row 5 times (because database is not changing here). You mark it for deleting 5 times. And then during submit you delete this row only.

Instead of making two queries (one for checking if entity exists, and other loading required entity) you can use single query:

```
var header = SFC.Systems_MonitoringMeasurementHeaders
           .FirstOrDefault(h => h.DocNO == DocNum.Text && 
                                h.DetailsDocNum == clsVariable.GetDocNumRecord);
if (header != null)   
    SFC.Systems_MonitoringMeasurementHeaders.DeleteOnSubmit(header);
```

Same with multiple entities (here you had 6 queries instead of one)

```
var details = SFC.Systems_MonitoringMeasurementDetails
                 .Where(d => d.DocNO == DocNum.Text &&
                             d.DetailsDocNum == clsVariable.GetDocNumRecord);

foreach(var detail in details)    
    SFC.Systems_MonitoringMeasurementDetails.DeleteOnSubmit(detail);

SFC.SubmitChanges();
```

Remember - until you call `SubmitChanges()` nothing is updated in database. If you do same query many times without changing database, it will return same data.

Comment: Big Thanks sir.. i have already come up with a solution i just got it right now before i have checked your answer but i'll use your answer instead of mine. i'll post my answer if you mind you can check it an tell me if there's something wrong. i'm still a student and studying on this language c# so i'm taking any comment i receive to expand knowledge on this language.

Comment: @Oblivious7 BTW instead of adding details for deletion in a loop, you can add them all at once with `DeleteAllOnSubmit(details)` call, as Channappa suggested. But don't use `Any()` - that will cause query to be executed twice

Comment: @Oblivious7 OK, I checked your solution. Currently you have one issue - both your queries executed twice. First SQL query returns count of entities, second downloads them. What you should do - execute query immediately by calling `ToList()`: `var details = SFC.Systems_MonitoringMeasurementDetails.Where(...).ToList()` in this case call to `Count()` will not generate new query. Also usage of `Any()` is little more descriptive than `Count() > 0`. And I'm not sure if you need this check for `DeleteAllOnSubmit` call. Maybe it does nothing if sequence is empty

Comment: @Oblivious7 and one more thing - you don't need to call people here `sir` :)

Answer (score 2):

I guess you didn't realize that you are deleting the first row 5 times.
Suggest using the `DeleteAllOnSubmit` method to delete multiple rows.

```
var tableDetails = SFC.Systems_MonitoringMeasurementDetails.Where(
                       y => y.DocNO == DocNum.Text && 
                       y.DetailsDocNum == clsVariable.GetDocNumRecord);

if(tableDetails.Any())
{
    SFC.Systems_MonitoringMeasurementDetails.DeleteAllOnSubmit(tableDetails);
}
```